# Using older mountain bike in a Trainer

Tags: mountain-bike, rear-wheel, trainer, skewer

I have an older mountain bike.  I need to change the rear skewer so I can use an indoor trainer, but I don't think there is one.  What do I do?

I have a CycleOps Mag trainer and they included a skewer to replace the one that is supposed to be on the bike.

Comment: Do you mean your bike has an axle held on with nuts?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Lyndse. Can you be more specific about how your bike is meant to attach to the trainer?

Comment: Right, there is an axle held on with nuts.  I have a CycleOps Mag trainer and they included a skewer to replace the one that is supposed to be on the bike.    I thought maybe my bike is just old, but I looked at some new bikes yesterday and noticed they don't have a rear skewer, either.

Comment: i figured it out.  can't take the axle out..too expensive to have it changed out..

Comment: Feel free to self-answer

Comment: I have used the nut style axle to attach to a BIKEMATE indoor trainer from Aldi. It worked without any problems and is very secure. My wife loves the new piece of gym equip.

Answer (score 4):

The point of the quick release skewer they give you with a trainer is generally to prevent damage to your fancy skewer already on your bike, and make sure the trainer can grip onto the axle properly. If you have a quick release system, you should use the provided skewer.

If you have a thru axle like a Maxle, you may need to buy a special adapter.

If you have a classic nutted axle (which you most likely have), you can generally use it directly in the trainer, but you may want to double check with the trainer manufacturer.

Comment: The provided skewer is often heavier steel, to replace a lighter-weight alloy skewer that you'd want to keep for real riding.   The trainers tend to marr the end of the skewer with clamping pressures.